Android .abb issue, app work fine in debug and release apk locally in testing but not in live app
I recently encountered an issue with my Android app where everything worked perfectly in debug mode, but when I published the release build to the Play Store, things started falling apart. It is actually vpn app in which I am using openVPN api. The app works fine both in debug and release apk in my devices but when I upload bundle .abb file to play console, and then download live app the app work fine to android 11 but not building connection on android 12 to 14. It is downloadin servers but when try to connecting it is causing issue. I want to upload bundle where the app should work like the apks are working. I have set minifyEnabled false, shrinkResources false both false. But issue is still there.
I am expecting to work app as it is woeking in debug and release in my side.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
